# sed cannot find file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I'm using sed in a bash script to change some variable values. These variables are mixture of different types and include also some special characters:

```
 sed -i -e "s/NPROC=[^,]*,/NPROC=$NPROC/" \
      -e "s/NFRPOS=[^,]*,/NFRPOS=$OUTPUTFREQ/" \
      -e "s/NFRHIS=[^,]*,/NFRHIS=$OUTPUTFREQ/" \
      -e "s/COSP_OUTPUT_FREQUENCY=[^,]*,/COSP_OUTPUT_FREQUENCY=$OUTPUTFREQ/" \
      -e "s/TSTEP=[^,]*,/TSTEP=$TSTEP/" \
      -e "s/NCEXTR=[^,]*,/NCEXTR=$NCEXTR/" \
      -e "s/NVXTR2=[^,]*,/NVXTR2=$NVXTR2/" \
      -e "s/NVEXTR=[^,]*,/NVEXTR=$NVEXTR/" \
      -e "s/COSP_NLEVELS=[^,]*,/COSP_NLEVELS=$NLEV/" \
      -e "s/NVEXTRAGB=[^,]*,/$NVEXTRAGB/" \
      -e "s/NVEXTR2GB=[^,]*,/$NVEXTR2GB/" \
      -e "s/NFPLEV=[^,]*,/NFPLEV=$NFPLEV/" \
      -e "s/CNMEXP=[^,]*,/CNMEXP=\"${EXPID}\"/" \
      -e "s/LFPOS=[^,]*,/NFPOS=2/" \
      -e "s/NLAT=[^,]*,/NLAT=$NLAT/" \
      -e "s/NLON=[^,]*,/NLON=$NLON/" \
         $NAMELIST


+ sed -i -e 's/NPROC=[^,]*,/NPROC=10/' ' '
sed: can't read  : No such file or directory
```

However, I keep getting the error that the file $NAMELIST cannot be found. The file does exits in the same directory and there is no error in the name. Adding the fullpath doesn't help either. So I'm wondering what is wrong in this sed command.

Comment: Where is the original error `$NAMELIST cannot be found`? The new error is easy to figure out. And you probably have an additional error `/path/to/namelist: Permission denied`.

Comment: The error was the addition of a space after the line continuation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space after the first backslash. Instead of escaping the newline to continue the command, you're escaping the space, so it thinks the name of the file to edit is a single space.

Make sure that the backslashes are the last character on every line.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks :-) Hard to notice an empty space.

Comment: You can use a text editor which automatically removes trailing spaces from a line, or at least displays invisible characters such as spaces. I personally am not fond of continuation lines anyway, exactly because of this kind of problems.

Comment: Good point. I was using emacs in terminal mode so I didn't see the problem. Also, one would have to know that a space would cause such an error in this case. It is not clear that such a benign character can cause such problems.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your NAMELIST variable is not being expanded.  Sed is looking for a file that is literally named "$NAMELIST" instead of say "/the/path/to/namelist.txt"...

Check whatever logic is setting the NAMELIST variable.

Comment: Adding the fullpath to the file and making the name explicit doesn't help. I'm new to sed so I suspect I missed something in the command.

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation is that `NAMELIST` literally contains the phrase "can't read ". To whit:

```
$ NAMELIST="can't read "
$ sed -e 1d "$NAMELIST"
sed: can't read : No such file or directory
```

How are you setting `NAMELIST`?

Comment: Hehe...I'm not so bad at coding in Bash. Namelist=namelist.t255.